# How to create a Sequelize model instance, without saving it in the database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Let's assume we have an Sequelize model called `Person`—how can we create an instance of `Person`, without saving it into the database?

This will create the record in the database:

```
Person.create({ name: "Alice" }).then(..., ...);
```

How to create a model instance without creating a record for it into the database?

---

The use-case is for creating multiple documents:

```
myFamily.addPersons([person1, person2, ...]);
```

When I try to pass raw objects into that array, an error appears: `val.replace is not a function` and as [suggested here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6598#issuecomment-247156171), the reason could be the fact I pass raw objects.

---

While I'm interested to know how to solve the problem, I'd want to know how to create Sequelize model instances, without saving them in the database.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you `build` one, it won't be saved into the db:

```
var person = Person.build({ name: "Alice" });
```

Or you can just instantiate the `Person` class:

```
const person = new Person({ name: "Alice" })
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Would be handy to leave a link to the docs as well.

Comment: Just a note: for my use case (adding persons to the family), I should use `create`, according to [this](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/864), otherwise the `Person`s won't be created.

Comment: How can you get the model's instance of a table that is already in a remote database. Im able to connect to a remote db. But instead of directly using query method to write extensive plain sql queries, can I use the ORM like functionality to query data from an existing table without defining the model in my node app?

Comment: Is there a way to get an object back that has all the fields in the model?  Say the model/table has 15 fields, can you get back an instance such that if you at least called toJSON on it, you'd get all 15 fields defined, even if they're empty?